# Can I stream iOS App Views to the Chromecast

Tags: android, ios, streaming, chromecast, apple-tv

Is there a possibility of streaming my app views (screen) to `Chromecast`?

I would like to use it as the way to my app, while not having the Apple TV (that is fully integrated with iOS, and allow for 1 to 1 streaming screen content).

Can I use Chromecast SDK to stream what's on the iDevice Screen in my application ?

Comment: you managed to achieve this ? will apple approve such an implementation ?

Comment: Was you able to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no api in the SDK to accomplish this. You can either create frames and send frames as a "video" stream or you can possibly use WebRTC for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [remote display](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote) feature.
Please note this is still marked as experimental and also require a device running at least iOS8